# Facebook login - error message: Value of optional type 'Any?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm fairly to new to Swift and got into some errors.

I am trying to create a Facebook login. I want to access the email address I login with.

I set the parameters like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {
    let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
    button.readPermissions = ["email"]
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.center = view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self

    if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current() {
    fetchProfile()
    }
}

func fetchProfile() {
    print("FETCdfsdffdssdfdsfsdgvfsebgrwntynbdtyndghHED")

    let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start {(connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog(error.debugDescription)
            return
        }

        // Result
        print("Result: \(result)")

        // Handle vars
        if let result = result as? [String:String],
            let email: String = result["email"],
            let fbId: String = result["id"] {
            print("Email: \(email)")
            print("fbID: \(fbId)")
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand the error and why it's complaining.

Comment: which part are you getting this error ? is it `print(error)`?

Comment: did you trying with this way  `print(error ?? "")` what is the print result when you trying  this way

Comment: would you try this way just `print("error: \(error)")` instated `print(error)` hope it will resolve your error

Comment: @NazmulHasan So the error was at-->                                                                             if let email = result["email"] as! String {              // build is failing on the email

Answer (score 0):

Try  following example in your project

**Swift - 3**

```
           // Parameters for Graph Request
            let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]

            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start {(connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    NSLog(error.debugDescription)
                    return
                }

                // Result
                print("Result: \(result)")

                // Handle vars
                if let result = result as? [String:String],
                    let email: String = result["email"],
                    let fbId: String = result["id"] {
                    print("Email: \(email)")
                    print("fbID: \(fbId)")
                }
            }
```

Comment: THANKS! your code ran however its not returning a email to. only the name and id...

Comment: can you show me all your code? because I get email and fid

Comment: Alright. so I updated my code on top. Thanks for helping me out VishalPethani

Comment: I think you got email and fbid too. Happy to help you @jaelee

Answer (score -1):

Use like this :

```
if let data = result as? [String: Any],
    let email = data["email"] {
    print(email)
}
```

Comment: this answer did not meet original question want and error